# paypal recurring gem - cancel or suspend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, rubygems

I am using https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring but I am not sure which method - cancel or suspend will stop the money from the subscriber to my site. I looked at the code on github but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: what are the routes to cancel the subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the `profile_id` that you get when you create the recurring profile.

With it you just need to create a Recurring object and call `cancel` on it.

```rb
ppr = PayPal::Recurring.new(:profile_id => "I-VCEL6TRG35CU")
response = ppr.cancel
puts response
```

If the cancellation was succeeded you'll receive a response that looks like this:

```rb
#<PayPal::Recurring::Response::ManageProfile:0x0000000b0ab8f0 @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @params={:PROFILEID=>"I-6TBFJJL5854D", :TIMESTAMP=>"2013-05-15T13:33:49Z", :CORRELATIONID=>"455e02f8d2795", :ACK=>"Success", :VERSION=>"72.0", :BUILD=>"5908853"}, @errors=[]>
```

You can also use another calls like `suspend` or `reactivate`.

Comment: i did this cancel code, but every time i am getting error like " profile is not active".wht should i do for resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Canel will cancel the subscription which will also stop the payment from the user same as suspend but in cancel you cannot reactivate the profile anymore. You can only reactive subscriptions only with suspended profiles.